# What happens when I upload a multi-audio video to YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I livestream video game tournaments. The videos I record have two audio tracks. The first track is a low-volume game sound, combined with commentary audio. The second track is just the normalized volume game sound.

When I upload this video to YouTube, what is going to happen? Will YouTube combine both audio tracks into a single track? Will it throw out track 2?

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youtube will encode the primary or default audio stream.

Youtube doesn't support multiple audio [streams](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/youtube/OtzjKBksQAo;context-place=topicsearchin/youtube/multiple$20audio). Neither does [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:107372).

Although, apparently, some videos like the 2012 Olympic streams did have it. Special handling by Youtube, I'm sure.

Comment: So it will throw out Track 2?

Comment: In the encoded versions, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Good news at the horizon. You should expect [Multi-audio tracks and descriptive audio feeds](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/129769858/updates-to-captions-and-audio-features-on-youtube?hl=en#:%7E:text=Multi-audio%20tracks,the%20coming%20quarters.) support in the near future. There's actually a [video demo](https://youtu.be/WaOKSUlf4TM) with this capability, which is kind of proof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative audio tracks would be nice, but definitely specialized to maybe alternate languages, or your case.  I think the closest you'll get to anything usable is with [ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ducking).

But if another channel is out of the question, how about offering up the second video with the second track as a link inside the video to something private or unlisted?